# Gem install ignore flags for nokogiri

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, libxml2

I'm trying to install nokogiri version 1.6.0 and have some issues with it.

```
$ gem install nokogiri -v '1.6.0' -- --with-xml2-dir=/usr/local/Cellar/libxml2/2.9.1 --with-xslt-dir=/usr/local/Cellar/libxslt/1.1.28
Building native extensions with: '--with-xml2-dir=/usr/local/Cellar/libxml2/2.9.1 --with-xslt-dir=/usr/local/Cellar/libxslt/1.1.28'
This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing nokogiri:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /Users/shamatov/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/bin/ruby extconf.rb --with-xml2-dir=/usr/local/Cellar/libxml2/2.9.1 --with-xslt-dir=/usr/local/Cellar/libxslt/1.1.28
Extracting libxml2-2.8.0.tar.gz into tmp/i686-apple-darwin11/ports/libxml2/2.8.0... OK
Running 'configure' for libxml2 2.8.0... OK
Running 'compile' for libxml2 2.8.0... OK
Running 'install' for libxml2 2.8.0... OK
Activating libxml2 2.8.0 (from /Users/shamatov/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/nokogiri-1.6.0/ports/i686-apple-darwin11/libxml2/2.8.0)...
Extracting libxslt-1.1.26.tar.gz into tmp/i686-apple-darwin11/ports/libxslt/1.1.26... OK
Running 'configure' for libxslt 1.1.26... OK
Running 'compile' for libxslt 1.1.26... OK
Running 'install' for libxslt 1.1.26... OK
Activating libxslt 1.1.26 (from /Users/shamatov/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/nokogiri-1.6.0/ports/i686-apple-darwin11/libxslt/1.1.26)...
checking for libxml/parser.h... *** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.
```

As you can see, I use: `--with-xml2-dir=/usr/local/Cellar/libxml2/2.9.1 --with-xslt-dir=/usr/local/Cellar/libxslt/1.1.28`
but extconf.rb uses libxml2-2.8.0.tar.gz
Same to xslt it uses libxslt-1.1.26.tar.gz

How to fix this issue, cause changing version is not an option actually?
thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to:

```
$ gem uninstall nokogiri # JIC
$ NOKOGIRI_USE_SYSTEM_LIBRARIES=1 gem install nokogiri \
    -- --use-system-libraries \
       --with-iconv-dir="$(brew --prefix libiconv)" \
       --with-xml2-config="$(brew --prefix libxml2)/bin/xml2-config" \
       --with-xslt-config="$(brew --prefix libxslt)/bin/xslt-config"
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks, that's awesome. Can you explain how it works? And why mine is incorrect

Comment: I don’t already remember what’s wrong with compiling bundled lib[xml,xslt] libraries on Mac, but the flag `NOKOGIRI_USE_SYSTEM_LIBRARIES=1` should be always turned on during nokogiri install. Nokogiri makes some weird assumptions about what libs are prefectly fit your system and always fails :) It’s needless to say that without that flag it tries to use bundled libs.